# Is it 'separatist-controlled territory' or 'separatists-controlled territory'?

Tags: grammar

Is it 'separatist-controlled territory' or 'separatist**s**-controlled territory'? There're, at the same time, 'five-year-old (child)' and 'right**s** (group)', different patterns. I understand that 'right (group)' would sound ambiguous so that plural flexion does serve a semantic purpose, but still. Again, don't suggest rephrasing (like 'the territory controlled by separatists')

Comment: I think both should hold good, because it (separatist) is a count-noun. It should also depend on the context.

Comment: The former. And only that.  `The separatists` are a group, so never used in the plural.

Comment: Indeed. In compound nouns such as this one, the first noun is mostly never pluralised. (Good rule of thumb, but careful as there exceptions of course: Commanders-in-chief, mothers-in-law)